# Is object garbage collected when removed from a static Map?

Tags: java, object, memory-management, garbage-collection

I have a static map in my application which populates when I click on a link.
After that it makes lots of objects and store them. Now I have a link which will clear this Map.

Here is my code.

```
Hello1 hello1 = new Hello1();
hello1.setHello("Helllollo1");
Hello hello = new Hello();
hello.setHello1(hello1);
hello.setHello("Hellollo");
setMap("1", (Object)hello);

Hello1 hello2 = new Hello1();
hello2.setHello("Helllollo1");
Hello helo = new Hello();
helo.setHello1(hello2);
helo.setHello("Hellollo");
setMap("2", (Object)helo);

Hello1 hello3 = new Hello1();
hello2.setHello("Helllollo1");
Hello helo1 = new Hello();
helo1.setHello1(hello3);
helo1.setHello("Hellollo");
setMap("3", (Object)helo1);
```

Now I have a method removeMap which works as below

```
public static void removeMap(String key){

        if(map.containsKey(key)){

            map.remove(key);
        }   
    }
```

So when I call this method for a single key after adding above three object, is that object Garbage Collected or not?

Comment: Eligibility for garbage collection is a very well documented topic, I suggest you do some research. You can also attach a profiler to your process and watch the number of objects that are currently living.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, after the map is cleared, the objects which were referenced from it will become eligible for garbage collection *if* there are no other strong references to them.

Note that removing the entry from the map won't immediately *cause* garbage collection - it just means the map will no longer be *preventing* the object from being garbage collected.

Answer (score 0):

Yes , When your `Map` is cleared or you remove objects from it , objects will be eligible for garbage collection . since objects don't have any reference they are eligible for GC.

Any object which is unreachable or has no reference is eligible for collection.

Answer (score 0):

Your question embodies a contradiction in terms. If the object, or rather the reference to the Object, has been removed from the Map, it is no longer 'inside the Map' at all.